# WPF DataGrid CellTemplateSelector Copy to Clipboard

Tags: wpf, datagrid, copy, clipboard

How can be the content of textBlock ("Example1" or "Example2") using CellTemplateSelector copied to clipboard?
ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding XXX}" works only for DataGridTemplateColumn without CellTemplateSelector.

Sample code:

```html
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate"> 
    <TextBlock Text="Example1"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate"> 
    <TextBlock Text="Example2"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector> 
         <local:TemplateSelector  
            FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" 
            SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: What is the logic in TemplateSelector that you use to change between FirstTemplate and SecondTemplate?

I think you can just add `ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"` to the `DataGridTemplateColumn` and implement the same logic in that converter. Giving back either `"Example1"` or `"Example2"`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The TemplateSelector has to be used instead of Converter. The logic is: public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate FirstTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate SecondTemplate { get; set; }
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,  DependencyObject container)
        {
          ....
                if (...)
                    return FirstTemplate;
                else
                    return SecondTemplate;
        }
    }